# Any standards for urban rainwater drainage network?

Tags: network, standards, precipitation

I am starting to work on a project related to urban drainage networks. Are there any standards out there to represent this kind of network? Relevant attributes would be things like pipe section, pipe length, pipe intake and outlet height.

I am awere the OGC has set up a work group developing [InfraGML](http://www.opengeospatial.org/blog/2098), but as far as I know it is not yet officially released.

Answer (score 2):

I work with our city's storm sewer team and they are required to keep all of their data in NASSCO formats and standards.  In addition to the attributes like material, length, etc, NASSCO standards give you the ability to rate the condition of the pipe and flag any defects in the pipe.  If you are planning on using a CCTV crew to inspect the pipes their work will (should) be delivered in a NASSCO compliant database.

http://www.nassco.org/publications/specs/sewer_cleaning_6Nov2014.pdf

http://www.nassco.org/publications/specs/spec_guidelines/definitions.pdf

http://nassco.org/publications/p_spec_guidelines.html